# Recursive method for palindrome checkup

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, palindrome

Is it even possible to define a recursive method for palindrome checkup with the following argument list?

```
int testPalindromeRecursive(char* str, int len) { ... }
```

Note: no external sub-functions or global variables have to be used

I think this is impossible, because you have to remember the last (front) index position somehow.

Comment: if char* str is a character array its possible.  You check the first and last element in each recursive step, and pass in the trimmed string (removing the front and last element if they match) until you reach an element of size 1 or 0.   I'm trying to recall in C if you even need the int len argument.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus You wouldn't have to trim it, since you don't have to use `strlen()` - the length is already passed in as `len`.

Comment: @PaulRoub how do you track how far from the beginning to start then?  You'd either need 2 variables for length or a trimmed character array

Comment: @MarshallTigerus i also thought about that solution but it's not quite efficient, don't you think

Comment: The trick is that `str` doesn't have to point at the start of the string; it can point to a _substring_. Then you use `len` to denote the length of the _substring_.

Comment: @neuronal.bit It's possible. It's actually a very simple function. Have you tried to implement this? If so, show your code and we'll help sort it out.

Comment: @PaulRoub I'm on it, just a sec :)

Comment: It is always possible to replace loops with recursion, if you have an aversion against fast programs, small memory consumption or readable code. If you like Stack Overflow(s) however, go for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is completely possible - as several people have mentioned.

Base Cases:

- If len <= 1, return True
- If str[0] != str[len-1] return False

Else: recurse with (str+1, len -2)

Comment: Points for not just handing OP the code, and for not needlessly trimming, copying, re-allocating the string.

Answer (score 1):

1) A string with no characters or just a single character is a palindrome

2) if the first and last characters of a string with 2 or more characters are equal, and the substring excluding the terminal characters is a palindrome, the whole string is a palindrone.

Answer (score 1):

As for me then I would declare the function like

```
int testPalindromeRecursive( const char *s, size_t n );
```

In this case the function would contain only one return statement

```
int testPalindromeRecursive( const char *s, size_t n ) 
{
    return ( n < 2 ) || 
           ( s[0] == s[n-1] && testPalindromeRecursive( s + 1, n - 2 ) );   
}
```

Nevertheless the function can be written the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int testPalindromeRecursive( char *str, int len ) 
{
    if ( len < 0 ) return 0;
    
    return ( len < 2 ) || 
           ( str[0] == str[len-1] && testPalindromeRecursive( str + 1, len - 2 ) );   
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "abbcccbba"; 

    printf( "testPalindromeRecursive( \"%s\" ) is %s\n",
            s, testPalindromeRecursive( s, sizeof( s ) - 1 ) ? "true" : "false" );
            
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
testPalindromeRecursive( "abbcccbba" ) is true
```

Take into account that you may adhere to the common convention according to which string functions do not check whether the passed character pointer is equal to NULL. It is the responsibility of the programmer to check this before the function call.

Comment: Kudos for the 'correct' signature using `const` and `size_t`

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to offer Python version here:

```
 def ispalindrome(word):
     if len(word) < 2: return True

     if word[0] != word[-1]:         # base condition
        return False

     return ispalindrome(word[1:-1]) # chop head/tail each loop

>>> ispalindrome('racecar')
True
>>> ispalindrome('racekcar')
False
>>> ispalindrome('a')
True
>>> ispalindrome('aba')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is capable of skipping whitespace:

```
int test_palindrom_recursive(char* str, int len)
{
    if (len < 1) return 0;
    int frontIndexToPass = 0, endIndexToPass = 0;
    if (str[0] == ' ')
    {
        for (int front = 0; front < len - 1; front++)
        {
            if (str[front] == ' ') frontIndexToPass++;
            else break;
        }
    }

    if (str[len - 1] == ' ')
    {
        for (int end = len - 1; end >= 0; end--)
        {
            if (str[end] == ' ') endIndexToPass++;
            else break;
        }
    }

    if (tolower(str[0 + frontIndexToPass]) == tolower(str[len - endIndexToPass - 1]))
    {
        if (len <= 2) return 1;
        else
            test_palindrom_rekursiv(str + frontIndexToPass + 1,
                len - endIndexToPass - frontIndexToPass - 2);
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `C#` I managed to get this:

```
int testPalindromeRecursive(string str, int len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
        return 0;

    if (str[0] == str[len - 1])
    {
        str = str.Substring(1, len - 2);
        return testPalindromeRecursive(str, str.Length);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

`ref` is doing almost the same job as `*` here. => **Removed `ref` because it was not the best option since it didn't allow the use of `const`**

Comment: Much Wow. Such DownVotes. No Explain :)

Comment: Sorry Thomas, one of those is mine by mistake and I can't revert it now!!

Comment: Done, best to have at least one code example with no down votes here

Comment: @Thomas What will be with the original string if you declared the first parameter as reference? Also whet the function will return for string "aa"? Also it is a bad idea to return 1 and -1 from the function. If you wrote the function in C# then it would be better if it had return type bool.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I don't care if the original string change as I pass it by reference since it's what the OP's asked for. He/She asked for a code that fit this signature, is recursive and find out if a string is a palindrome. This is what I do in my code. It works fine for "aa" :)

Comment: @Thomas Your function is invalid and the OP did not say that the original string may be changed. It is simply a bad idea to change the original string that only to test whether it is a palindrome.:) After that he will be unable even to output the string that to say what string is a palindrome.:)

Comment: @Thomas 1) It can not be applied to constant string and 2) it will return 0 for strings like "aa" will not it?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes it will, since (in my case) 0 is success and -1 is failure. Agreed with const string, I didn't think about that !

Comment: @Thomas It is not a good interface because usually such functions return eeither true in case of the success or false in case of the failure. In C any non-zero value is considered as true. So you may use the function in if statement simply like if( testPalindromeRecursive( s, n ) ) { /*...*/}

Comment: @Thomas Usually -1 is used to signal some kind of error. As for this function then there is no error. There is a logical question whether a string is a palindrome.

Answer (score -1):

This works just fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int testPalindromeRecursive(char* str, int len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
        return 1;

    if (str[0] != str[len-1])
        return 0;

    return testPalindromeRecursive(str+1, len-2);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char *strs[5] = { "test", "tvt", "a", "palindrome", "racecar" };

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%s = %d\n", strs[i], testPalindromeRecursive(strs[i], strlen(strs[i])));
}
```

Edit: Fix according to comments to check for length==0 as well

Comment: You need to test for length == 0 --- `testPalindromeRecursive("oo", 2);` or `testPalindromeRecursive("opqrstuvwwvutsrqpo", 2);`

Answer (score -2):

[EDIT2]
This is the correct answer in C. Although it has been downvoted three times, I'm keeping it as it's the ONLY correct answer in C on this page.

[EDIT]
fixed my answer.

In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int testPalindromeRecursive(char* str, int len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
        return 0;
    if (str[0] != str[len-1])
        return 1;
    return testPalindromeRecursive(str+1, len-2);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    if (!testPalindromeRecursive(argv[1], strlen(argv[1])))
        printf("Palindrom\n");
    else
        printf("Not palindrom\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Running example for the case mentioned in a comment by kdopen (base case failure when testPalindromeRecursive("a", 1):

```
./palind a  
Palindrom
```

More running examples mentioned by kdopen:

./mine \"a <-- the \ is to escape the "
Not palindrom

./mine \"\"
Palindrom

Comment: This will fail in a variety of ways. Not sure if it will ever succeed other than 0- or 1-character strings.

Comment: @PaulRoub Please explain

Comment: it should be len-2 in the second call to testPalindromeRecursive and it should also return true if length is 1

Comment: See, for example here, where it thinks "tort" is a palindrome: https://ideone.com/nYJi75

Comment: Someone's pushing the downvote pretty hard... Easy guys, we all make mistakes! every answer in this post has been downvoted at least once...

Comment: @IshayPeled You base case still fails for a call such as `testPalindromeRecursive("a",1)`. Also, please remove the "Thanks"

Comment: @kdopen can you provide a running example where it fails? I tried ./palind a and it works. Also, why remove the thanks?

Comment: What does it return with a string of "a" or ""? Those are palindromes and you return 00 (i.e. false). Actually you are using a value of 1 for true in the next test. Re: the 'thanks' see the answer to [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)

Comment: @kdopen sorry mate... Please run the code. It works. a 0 value is true here, mind the !testPalindromRecursive line. I added more running examples for your cases. Please run the code for yourself if you really want to be sure. I'm keeping this answer on for the sake of someone seeking a correct answer in C.

Comment: Your `main` program deals with the logical inversion, but it's a non-idiomatic usage and likely to confuse people looking at your code.

Comment: @kdopen I trust the good reader to handle logical inversions. I usually run code before I conclude it doesn't work (;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77524/discussion-between-ishay-peled-and-kdopen).